# android intent-filter to listen for sent email addresses?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like my app to be able to respond when an email address is "sent" in an intent. for example, when a user clicks on an email address in the contacts app, the gmail and email apps show up. i'd like to get into that list.

my first attempt was to match on scheme="mailto",

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent-filter>
```

which did not work. next attempt was to match pathPattern=".*@.*".

```
            <data android:pathPattern=".*@.*" />
```

this didn't work, and as the JD's say, that's only meaningful if the host, scheme is specified.

any ideas?

Comment: If don't mind please give u'r sample application related to above post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Email app uses](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob_plain;f=AndroidManifest.xml;h=eec7772abe6804a5fb37cd312d2893482c6d8638;hb=HEAD):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
    <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```