# Android, How to add my application to appear when user clicks on an e-mail address

Tags: android, email, drop-down-menu

Using Android, when I click on an e-mail address in my default browser, a menu list pops up with Gmail, (an built-in email client), and K-9 (another e-mail application).

I would like to add my android application to appear in this list.  Is this possible and how do I do this?

Comment: Very broadly, your app needs to be registered to handle broadcast intents of type email. I believe it is a manifest change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this intent-filter  to  your activity  in manifiest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an `IntentFilter` this requires both Java code, where you create an `Activity` that is triggered when the system notifies someone is trying to send an email, and changes to your `AndroidManifest` where you subscribe to the `Intent` action. Here is an SO Post that explains which intent filters you need: [android intent-filter to listen for sent email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796059/android-intent-filter-to-listen-for-sent-email-addresses)

You add these to your `Activity` entry in your `AndroidManifest` and then when someone clicks an email it'll show your app. when someone clicks it, it'll open that specific `Activity` you are going to want to read about pulling data out of intents. Specifically you'll want to pull out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL from the extras.

Answer (score 1):

Read about intent-filter here:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html