# How to Open Native Mail on Android Device using React Native as Done with 'Linking.openURL()' iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

How to open native mail on android device using react native. 
I currently am using `Linking.openURL()` but that only works for iOS.

I am trying to open native mail on android device using React Native. I currently am using `Linking.openURL(url)` and this works no problem for iOS devices but does not work for android devices.

Please advise if you can. Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to open the mail app or do you want to use mailto: to start composing a mail?

Comment: i want to open the mail app and compose a mail on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by going into the android.manifest.xml and added the following intent, this allows me to open email on android. hope it helps someone!

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
    <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

answer was found here [android intent-filter to listen for sent email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796059/android-intent-filter-to-listen-for-sent-email-addresses)